How to align TikZ nodes in different environments to the dimensions of the current line?
What I'm trying to do
I'm trying to typeset what is shown in the following graphic using LaTeX. The graphic was created using Inkscape.

Note that ...

all texts (including the numbers inside the black rectangles) regardless of the dimensions of any character in the word are aligned
the red lines at the the right side of the words have the same height.
the red lines at the bottom side of the words are aligned.

What I've tried
I defined the macro \annotation[2] which receives two parameters: the first parameter is the number which is shown in the black rectangle and the second parameter is the word that appears next to the black rectangle and have the red borders on the bottom and on the right. See result in the screenshot below.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\annotation}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(mynode.base)]
    \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (mynode) {#2};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt, anchor=east, fill=black, text=white, minimum size=1em] (number) at (mynode.west) {#1};
    \draw[red](mynode.south east) -- (mynode.north east);
    \draw[red](mynode.south west) -- (mynode.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
This is a paragraph. \annotation{1}{foo} \annotation{10}{bar} \annotation{100}{g} \annotation{10}{j} \annotation{1}{y}.
\end{document}


This has some flaws:

The red border at the bottom should be aligned with the bottom border of the black rectangle.
There's a small gap between the red border on the bottom and the red border on the right.
All text (including numbers) is not aligned.

These flaws are highlighted in the image below.

I'm not interested in fixing the highlighted flaws. If there's another way of accomplishing the result that is shown in the screenshot above, then that would be enough.

Okular-on-X produces worthless images right now, but the following seems to meet your desiderata:
\newcommand{\annotation}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(mynode.base)]
    \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (mynode) {#2\strut};

We add \strut to the contents of both nodes so we get the same height regardless of ascenders and descenders.
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt, fill=black, text=white, minimum size=1em,anchor=base east] (number) at (mynode.base west) {#1\strut};

We want to align the nodes on the baseline. This shouldn't matter given we're using \struts except that the word node is 1pt higher and 1pt deeper than the number node due to the difference in inner sep. This still should be fine, given we're aligning east to west, but it seems more reliable to align on the baseline, so I did it anyway. baseline east to baseline west should be right even if something else changes or is slightly off.
    \draw[red](mynode.south west) ++(0pt,{\pgflinewidth+1pt})  -| ([yshift=-1pt]mynode.north east) ;

We want to draw the two sides as a single path to avoid the gap. We also need to compensate for the difference in inner sep and for the width of the border of the nodes, since we're not drawing it for the left node. So 1pt adjustment at each end and \pgflinewidth at the bottom. If you want to be even more precise, you could use yshift=-\pgflinewidth-1pt, but it doesn't really show, so I didn't bother.
Another option would be to specify zero line width when creating the nodes, but you would still have to adjust by half the \pgflinewidth and for the 1pt, so you don't really gain anything.
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

Complete code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\annotation}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(mynode.base)]
    \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (mynode) {#2\strut};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt, anchor=east, fill=black, text=white, minimum size=1em,anchor=base east] (number) at (mynode.base west) {#1\strut};
    \draw[red](mynode.south west) ++(0pt,{\pgflinewidth+1pt})  -| ([yshift=-1pt]mynode.north east) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
This is a paragraph. \annotation{1}{foo} \annotation{10}{bar} \annotation{100}{g} \annotation{10}{j} \annotation{1}{y}.
\end{document}


If you set inner xsep=1pt, inner ysep=0pt for mynode, you'd avoid the need to compensate without affecting the result as the node is neither filled nor drawn.


With tikz and the shapes.multipart library, 71.6 Shapes with Multiple Text Parts and using the cfr recommendations (\strut, baseline).
EDIT with tabular and colortbl

With tikz
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/717300/how-to-align-tikz-nodes-in-different-environments-to-the-dimensions-of-the-curre
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\NewDocumentCommand{\annotation}{ m m }
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \node[%
            name=s,
            anchor=base,
            rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=2,
            rectangle split part align=base,
            rectangle split horizontal,
            outer sep = 0pt,
            rectangle split part fill={black,white},
            inner sep=1pt
            ]
            {
                \nodepart{one}\textcolor{white}{\bfseries #1}
                \nodepart{two}\textcolor{black}{\bfseries#2\strut}
            };
            \draw [red]([yshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]s.one split south)-|(s.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%<-- don't forget
}
\begin{document}
This is a paragraph. \annotation{1}{foo} \annotation{10}{bar} \annotation{100}{g} \annotation{10}{j} \annotation{1}{y}.
\end{document}


With tabular
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/717300/how-to-align-tikz-nodes-in-different-environments-to-the-dimensions-of-the-curre

\usepackage{colortbl}
\ExplSyntaxOn%<-- to avoid spurious spaces
\NewDocumentCommand{\annotation}{ m m }
    {   
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
        \begin{tabular}{| >{\color{white}\columncolor{black}} c  c !{\color{red}\vrule} }
            #1&#2\\\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
        \end{tabular}%<-- don't forget
    \endgroup%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
This is a paragraph. \annotation{1}{foo} \annotation{10}{bar} \annotation{100}{g} \annotation{10}{j} \annotation{1}{y}.

\end{document}


